# Помогите найти ошибку в коде. sql and php and html

Tags: php, html, sql

ДД. Помогите найти в чем проблема. Создала форму на сейте для добавления записи в БД.
Но почему- то после заполнения формы и нажатия кнопки ок, форма пропадает с вкладки. После обновления страницы, форма не появляется, спасает только снова нажать на кнопку страницы в шапке сайта.

```
    <?php   
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM KOMMUNALKA";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
     
    echo "<table class='komun'><tr><th>Дата</th><th>Квартплата</th><th>ПЭС</th><th>КапРемонт</th><th>Мусор</th><th>Итог</th></tr>";
    foreach($result as $row){
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["DATA"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["KVARTPLATA"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["PES"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["KAPREMONT"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["MUSOR"] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["ITOG"] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_free_result($result);
} else{
    echo "Ошибка: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
 ?>
 
 <?php
  //Если переменная DATE передана
  if (isset($_POST["DATE"])) {
    //Вставляем данные, подставляя их в запрос
    $sql = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO `KOMMUNALKA` (`DATE`, `KVARTPLATA`, `PES`, `KAPREMONT`, `MUSOR`, `ITOG`) VALUES ('{$_POST['DATE']}', '{$_POST['KVARTPLATA']}', '{$_POST['PES']}', '{$_POST['KAPREMONT']}', '{$_POST['MUSOR']}', '{$_POST['ITOG']}')");
    //Если вставка прошла успешно
    if ($sql) {
      echo '<p>Данные успешно добавлены в таблицу.</p>';
    } else {
      echo '<p>Произошла ошибка: ' . mysqli_error($link) . '</p>';
    }
  }
?>
 <form action="" method="post" class="plus">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Дата:</td>
      <td><input type="DATE" name="DATE"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Квартплата:</td>
      <td><input type="varchar" name="KVARTPLATA" size="15"> руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ПЭС:</td>
      <td><input type="varchar" name="PES" size="15"> руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Капремонт:</td>
      <td><input type="varchar" name="KAPREMONT" size="15"> руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Мусор:</td>
      <td><input type="varchar" name="MUSOR" size="15"> руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Итог:</td>
      <td><input type="varchar" name="ITOG" size="15"> руб.</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="OK"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `$conn`, `$link`, закрытие соединения с базой посреди скрипта. Пожалуйста, разберись что у тебя в коде происходит.

Comment: Скажите, вы настроены учиться, как делать правильно? И в целом, вы готовы как-то реагировать на то что вам пишут? или вы из тех, кто зачем-то задает вопрос, а потом про него не вспоминает?

Comment: как раз и учусь и вот не могу понять в чем проблема

Comment: Чтобы понять, вам уже написали - вы пытаетесь сделать запрос после того, как закрыли соединение с базой данных. Но в общем случае понимать как раз не обязательно, достаточно прочитать. У вас происходит ошибка при обращении к базе данных, но вы её не видите. Чтобы увидеть, надо настроить отображение ошибок. Как настроить, написано по ссылке, прикрепленной вверху вашего поста. В ошибке будет написано,какая конкретно проблема.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в action у формы прописать путь до скрипта. Возможно (если вы пробуете в браузере Safari), переход идёт не на текущий скрипт, а в /

Кроме того, возможно возникает "ошибка 500" в скрипте, и веб сервер не настроен на её отображение. Посмотрите результат выполнения скрипта в консоли браузера.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Там и логика и форма в одном файле.

Comment: В целом, фраза "веб сервер не настроен на её отображение" является правильной. Но идущее следом "Посмотрите результат выполнения скрипта в консоли браузера" - это полное непонимание как собственного совета. так и в принципе того, как работает веб-сервер.

Comment: Эмм.. вы видимо забыли или не знаете, что если например у того же PHP в настройках не указано "показывать все ошибки", то в случае падения оного, в случае например синтаксической ошибки, ошибка в ответе вернется лишь в заголовках ответа. Это то как раз отлично и видно в консоли браузера.

Comment: И что там в заголовках ответа будет? В каком заголовке будет текст\описание ошибки? И откуда в заголовках возьмется инфа об ошибке, если в настройках не указано "показывать все ошибки"?

Comment: Как минимум номер ошибки: 500, 403 и т.д. Этого достаточно, чтобы понять в чем проблема. Если нужны подробности, то естественно нужно уже будет идти в логи сервера.  NewProgr1999 ведь спрашивает, "почему белый экран". Заглянет в консоль и увидит ошибку 500. Заглянет в логи и увидит более подробный текст

Comment: Так это не заголовок ответа, это код состояния.

Comment: Во-первых, там не белый экран. во-вторых, чтобы посмотреть в логи, смотреть сначала в консоль не обязательно. Можно СРАЗУ туда смотреть. А в третьих,  в вашем ответе про логи ничего нет, что делает его бесполезным. Проблема всех приходящих сюда доброхотов в том, что они не считают нужным хотя бы немного потрудиться над ответом, и просто кидают какую-то реплику. Надо или прикладывать больше усилий, или найти себе другое место для самовыражения.